# Creating "exponential smoothing" variables - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with IDs, and choices that have made by those IDs.
The alternatives (choices) set is a list of integers: [10, 20, 30, 40].
Note: That's important to use this list. Let's call it 'choice_list'.

This is the data frame:

```
ID  Choice
1   10
1   30
1   10
2   40
2   40
2   40
3   20
3   40
3   10
```

I want to create a variable for each alternative: '10_Var', '20_Var', '30_Var', '40_Var'.
At the first row of each ID, if the first choice was '10' for example, so the variable '10_Var' will get the value 0.6 (some parameter), and each of the other variables ('20_Var', '30_Var', '40_Var') will get the value (1 - 0.6) / 4.
The number 4 stands for the number of alternatives.

How should the data look like after the step above:

```
ID  Choice  10_Var  20_Var  30_Var  40_Var
1   10      0.6     0.1     0.1     0.1
1   30              
1   10              
2   40      0.1     0.1     0.1     0.6
2   40              
2   40              
3   20      0.1     0.6     0.1     0.1
3   40              
3   10
```

From the second row and so on, the variable '10_Var' for example, will get the value: ( (0.6 * Previous-value) + (1 - 0.6) * {1 if the last choice was 10, 0 otherwise} ), and so for each variable.

Note: It should be done for each ID.

Expected result:

```
ID  Choice  10_Var  20_Var  30_Var  40_Var
1   10      0.6     0.1     0.1     0.1
1   30      0.76    0.06    0.06    0.06
1   10      0.456   0.036   0.436   0.036
2   40      0.1     0.1     0.1     0.6
2   40      0.06    0.06    0.06    0.76
2   40      0.036   0.036   0.036   0.856
3   20      0.1     0.6     0.1     0.1
3   40      0.06    0.76    0.06    0.06
3   10      0.036   0.456   0.036   0.436
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might be easier to understand, compared to previous solutions. It might be slower though (tests on large dataframes are required).

Also, it is parametrized, as asked by the user.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Parameter
P = 0.6

def exp_smooth(g):
    rows = [np.where(choices == g.iloc[0].Choice, P, (1-P)/len(choices))]
    for i in range(len(g) - 1):
        rows.append(rows[-1]*P+(1-P)*np.where(choices == g.iloc[i].Choice, 1, 0))
    return np.array(rows)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [1, 30], [1, 10],
                   [2, 40], [2, 40], [2, 40],
                   [3, 20], [3, 40], [3, 10]],
                  columns=('ID', 'Choice'))
choices = np.unique(df.Choice)

var_arr = np.concatenate([exp_smooth(g) for _, g in df.groupby("ID")], axis=0)
var_df = pd.DataFrame(var_arr, columns=[f"var_{c}" for c in choices])
df = pd.concat([df, var_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df=df.sort_values('ID')
print(df)
n=df['Choice'].nunique()
mask=df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift())

for choice in df['Choice'].sort_values(ascending=False).unique():
    mask2=df.groupby('ID')['Choice'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(choice).shift(fill_value=False))
    df.insert(2,column=f'{choice}_Var',value=np.nan)
    df.loc[mask,f'{choice}_Var']=np.where(df.loc[mask,'Choice'].eq(choice),0.6,0.4/n)
    df.loc[mask2,f'{choice}_Var']=(df.shift().loc[mask2].fillna(1)*0.6).groupby('ID')[f'{choice}_Var'].cumprod()+0.4
    df.loc[~(mask|mask2),f'{choice}_Var']=(df.shift().loc[~(mask|mask2)].fillna(1)*0.6).groupby('ID')[f'{choice}_Var'].cumprod()
    df.loc[mask2,f'{choice}_Var']=(df.shift().loc[mask2].fillna(1)*0.6).groupby('ID')[f'{choice}_Var'].cumprod()+0.4
print(df)

   ID  Choice  10_Var  20_Var  30_Var   40_Var
0   1      10   0.600   0.100   0.100  0.10000
1   1      30   0.760   0.060   0.060  0.06000
2   1      10   0.456   0.036   0.436  0.03600
3   2      40   0.100   0.100   0.100  0.60000
4   2      40   0.060   0.060   0.060  0.76000
5   2      40   0.036   0.036   0.036  0.56416
6   3      20   0.100   0.600   0.100  0.10000
7   3      40   0.060   0.760   0.060  0.06000
8   3      10   0.036   0.456   0.036  0.43600
```

Comment: The results are different. The value 0.4 added should be conditional, it should be multiplied by 1 if the previous choice was the specific variable, or multiplied by 0 otherwise.

Comment: I update my solution. 
This is a difficult problem to solve. Surely there are better solutions than this

Comment: It's good. I want to check it on my data. Please tell me, if there are other variables in my data, that I don't want to touch them, how should the code look like? Thanks

Comment: depend on where are this variables. 
I don't think it affects the code, because it's always being written on the new columns

Comment: Yea, it is. I've tried it. Maybe separate the data and then concatenate?

Comment: I've got this error: TypeError: Could not operate 0.6 with block values can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: use df.astype(float).sort_values('ID') instead

Comment: Still the same error. It happens on this line: df.loc[mask2,f'{choice}_Var']=(df.shift().loc[mask2].fillna(1)*0.6).groupby('ID')[f'{choice}_Var'].cumprod()+0.4

Comment: I don't understand why you have this error, you need to have a more extensive version of your data frame and the type of data you are using

Comment: May I send you an email with a sample data in csv file?

Comment: Yes, i will be glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using numpy vectorization. Basically what I did is break down the recursive operation into product and addition terms like below

1st let's take only one `var_xx` lets say `var_10` column and represent it with vector X

`X=[x1,x2,...,xi,....xn]`

then lets use vector Y to represent if last value in X is 10. It will be vector of boolean or (1,0)

`Y = [y1,y1,...,yi,...yn]`

now to calculate xi we can use this expression

`xi = x0*(0.6)^i + 0.4(y0*0.6^i + y1*0.6^(i-1) ... + yi*0.6^(i-i))`

in the code below `arr` is the 1st term and `(add2.T[:, np.newaxis, :] * add1).sum(axis=2).T` is the 2nd term

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [1, 30], [1, 10], [1, 10], [1, 10], [2, 40], [2, 40], [2, 40], [3, 20], [3, 40], [3, 10]], columns=('ID', 'Choice'))
choices = np.unique(df.Choice)
col_names = [f"var_{choice}" for choice in choices]

def exp_smooth(g):
    g=g.copy()
    arr = np.zeros((len(g), len(choices)))
    arr[0] = np.where(choices == g.iloc[0].Choice, 0.6, 0.1)
    arr[1:] = 0.6
    arr.cumprod(axis=0, out=arr)

    add1 = np.tri(len(g), k=-1)*0.6

    add1[(np.tri(len(g), k=-1)-np.tri(len(g), k=-2))==1] = 0.4
    add1[add1!=0] = np.where(add1==0,1,add1).cumprod(axis=0)[add1!=0]
    add1 = np.roll(add1, 1, axis=1)
#     display(add1)

    add2 = g.Choice.shift().values[:, np.newaxis] == choices[np.newaxis, :]
#     display(add2)
    result = (add2.T[:, np.newaxis, :] * add1).sum(axis=2).T + arr

    return g.assign(**{col:result[:,i] for i, col in enumerate(col_names)})

df.groupby("ID").apply(exp_smooth).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
# g = df.groupby("ID")
# g = g.get_group(2).copy()
# exp_smooth(g)
```

**Result**

```
    ID  Choice  var_10  var_20  var_30  var_40
0   1   10  0.60000 0.10000 0.10000 0.10000
1   1   30  0.76000 0.06000 0.06000 0.06000
2   1   10  0.45600 0.03600 0.43600 0.03600
3   1   10  0.67360 0.02160 0.26160 0.02160
4   1   10  0.80416 0.01296 0.15696 0.01296
5   2   40  0.10000 0.10000 0.10000 0.60000
6   2   40  0.06000 0.06000 0.06000 0.76000
7   2   40  0.03600 0.03600 0.03600 0.85600
8   3   20  0.10000 0.60000 0.10000 0.10000
9   3   40  0.06000 0.76000 0.06000 0.06000
10  3   10  0.03600 0.45600 0.03600 0.43600
```

**NOTE**: I have added few rows in group 1 for testing

Comment: My hat's off to you, Dev. Thank you